# Socket.io not working https over tls

Tags: node.js, sockets

i am working on chat application which is node based using socket.io and express chatting working fine on localhost but when i run my application online then it's having problem to connect because it's url with https i find some tutorial for connecting with https but i still doubt that my problem is TLS because i have not much idea for this so in short i want to say that socket.io not working over https TLS

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fr7v.jpg)

Here is my Server Code

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var forceSsl = require('express-force-ssl');

app.use(forceSsl);
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(3000,function(){
        console.log("Https server started on port 3000");
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Are your SSL credentials trusted by the browser?  Or self-signed?

Comment: when i read tutorial they write some command for creating self certified key etc then i follow command and put them in my code which is following :

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};

Comment: The browser will not connect to a server using a self created cert by default.

Comment: then what should i need to do can you please help me ?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how to do it.  You can certainly find it on the web with searching.  The browser will have to be configured to trust your cert before it will allow a connection to it.  Or, go get a trusted certificate here: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: i want to ask you one thing that i have ssl certificate installed on my domain
 so i need that .key  , .cert file for that sorry if i am wrong and make me correct.

Comment: try this article, it might help: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9834/69/how-can-i-find-the-private-key-for-my-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add your own ssl certificate if you have from your cpanel or you can talk to your hosting provider may be they can help because i also face same problem then i do same thing but i found my ssl certificate from cpanel so i think you need to check over there